# Web2py angularjs module

Tags: web2py

I have a problem with just trying to make an AngularJS module work in web2py.

specifically this cart: http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs

I read online that you have to change the delimiters in AngularJS which I did. (I resorted to changing the Angular file itself though, couldn't get the appname.config to work properly.)

When I try to copy the demo on the site it doesn't seem to activate the ngCart.js. Just the plain test is shown with.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

here is my attempt at it:

```
    {{extend 'layout.html'}}
        <head>

<script src="{{=URL('static','js/ngCart.min.js')}}"></script>
<script >//<![CDATA[

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngCart']);



myApp.controller ('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngCart', function($scope, $http, ngCart) {
    ngCart.setTaxRate(7.5);
    ngCart.setShipping(2.99);

}]);


</script>


</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-4">
    <h3>Summary <span>(ngCart-summary)</span></h3>

      <ngcart-summary></ngcart-summary>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
         <h3>Add to Cart <span>(ngCart-addtocart)</span></h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <h4>My Item #1</h4>
        <p> $10.99</p>
        <ngcart-addtocart id="item1" name="My Item #1" price="10.99" quantity="1" quantity-max="5">Add to Cart</ngcart-addtocart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <h4>My Item #2</h4>
        <p> $15.29</p>
        <ngCart-addtocart id="item2" name="My Item #2" price="15.29" quantity="1" quantity-max="5">Add to Cart</ngCart-addtocart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <h4>My Item #3</h4>
        <p> $25.75</p>
        <ngCart-addtocart id="item3" name="My Item #3" price="25.75" quantity="3" quantity-max="10">Add to Cart</ngCart-addtocart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <h4>My Item #4</h4>
        <p> $29.25</p>
        <ngCart-addtocart id="item4" name="My Item #4" price="29.25" quantity="1" quantity-max="10">Add to Cart</ngCart-addtocart>
    </div>
</div>

    <hr/>
    <h3>Cart <span> (ngCart-cart)</span></h3>

    <ngCart-cart></ngCart-cart>

    <hr/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <h3>Checkout <span> (ngCart-checkout)</span></h3>


        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>service 'log'</h4>
        <ngCart-checkout service="log">Checkout</ngCart-checkout>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>service 'http'</h4>
        <ngCart-checkout service="http" settings="httpSettings">Checkout </ngCart-checkout>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>service 'paypal'</h4>
        <ngCart-checkout service="paypal" settings="payPalSettings"></ngCart-checkout>
    </div>
</div>



    </div>
</div>

</div>


<!--  TEMPALATES -->
<!--  TEMPALATES -->
<!--  TEMPALATES -->

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/ngCart/summary.html">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">[[ ngCart.getTotalItems() ]]
        <ng-pluralize count="ngCart.getTotalItems()" when="{1: 'item', 'other':'items'}"></ng-pluralize>
        <br />[[ ngCart.totalCost() | currency ]]
    </div>
</div>
</script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/ngCart/cart.html">
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems() === 0">
    Your cart is empty
</div>

<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems() > 0">

    <table class="table table-striped ngCart cart">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr ng-show="ngCart.getTax()">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tax ([[ ngCart.getTaxRate() ]]%):</td>
            <td>[[ ngCart.getTax() | currency ]]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="ngCart.getShipping()">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Shipping:</td>
            <td>[[ ngCart.getShipping() | currency ]]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>[[ ngCart.totalCost() | currency ]]</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ngCart.getCart().items track by $index">
            <td><span ng-click="ngCart.removeItemById(item.getId())" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>

            <td>[[ item.getName() ]]</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ng-class="{'disabled':item.getQuantity()==1}"
                      ng-click="item.setQuantity(-1, true)"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                [[ item.getQuantity() | number ]]&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="item.setQuantity(1, true)"></span></td>
            <td>[[ item.getPrice() | currency]]</td>
            <td>[[ item.getTotal() | currency ]]</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/ngCart/addtocart.html">
    <div ng-hide="attrs.id">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-disabled="true" ng-transclude></a>

</div>
<div ng-show="attrs.id">
    <div>
        <span ng-show="quantityMax">
            <select name="quantity" id="quantity" ng-model="q"
                    ng-options=" v for v in qtyOpt"></select>
        </span>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
           ng-click="ngCart.addItem(id, name, price, q, data)"
           ng-transclude></a>
    </div>
    <mark  ng-show="inCart()">
        This item is in your cart. <a ng-click="ngCart.removeItemById(id)" style="cursor: pointer;">Remove</a>
    </mark>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/ngCart/checkout.html">

<div ng-if="service=='http' || service == 'log'">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="checkout()" ng-disabled="!ngCart.getTotalItems()" ng-transclude>Checkout</button>
</div>


<div ng-if="service=='paypal'">

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems()">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="[[ settings.paypal.business ]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="[[ settings.paypal.item_name ]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="[[ settings.paypal.item_number ]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="[[ ngCart.getSubTotal()]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="[[ settings.paypal.currency_code ]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="[[ ngCart.getTaxRate()]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="[[ ngCart.getShipping()]]">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>

</div>

</script>


</body>
```

Comment: I would change wep2py's delimiters, not angular's. Otherwise you have to change them for every angular component you bring in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but the layout most likely already has `<head>` and `<body>` tags (wouldn't be of much use otherwise). When you create a view that extends a layout, everything inside your view goes in the place of the `{{include}}` directive within the body of the layout. So, your final rendered HTML will have additional `<head>` and `<body>` tags within the `<body>` tag of the layout.

Instead, write your view assuming it is already inside a `<body>` tag. If you do need to insert something into the `<head>` of the layout, you can use a [block](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Blocks-in-views).

For more details, see the [layout](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Page-layout) documentation.